# How to get maximum for this data type in haskell

Tags: haskell

This is my method

```
data Arbre = Feuille Int | Noad [Arbre]

maximum1 :: Arbre -> Int
maximum1 (Feuille a) = a
maximum1 (Noad xs) = maximum1 xs...
```

Comment: Why is this called `maximum1`? What do you want returned for `Noad []`?

Comment: Also, what did you try, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: If you use `map maximum1 xs` you get a list with the maxima of each subtree. You then need to compute the maximum of the list (and handle the empty case somehow).

Comment: it's a method that get a maximum of a Tree (Arbre = Tree, Feuille = leaf) i want it to get the maximum of a Tree for Noad [] i don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, since your data type is either

1. A type containing an Integer, or
2. A list recursively of itself

So if you're checking for the max of all values in this structure, you have to recursively check each list. You want to call the max between each step you are in the recursion and the next step.

```
data Arbre = Feuille Int | Noad [Arbre]

maximum1 :: Arbre -> Int
maximum1 (Feuille a) = a
maximum1 (Noad (x:xs)) = max (maximum1 x) (maximum1 (Noad xs))
maximum1 (Noad []) = 0
```

The tricky part is you need to pattern match for the head of the list of Arbres and the tail, then recompose the tail in a Noad to be able to call function recursively. Also check for the case that Noad is empty (this solution assumes positive Integers).

Comment: Thank you it helps!